# Drupal symbolic link to another directory outside Drupal

Tags: drupal, apache2, directory, symlink

I have a multi-site Drupal setup http://mysite.com  which is in /home/drupal

I want the path http://mysite.com/iphone/ to point to a directory outside of Drupal on my server /home/iphone.

Here is the entry in the vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.244:80>             
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@mysite.com                  
    DocumentRoot /home/drupal       
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com www.mysite.com www.mysite.com mysite.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite5_err_log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite5_log special
    <Directory /home/drupal>
                Options FollowSymLinks +Includes ExecCGI       
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    </Directory>            
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this done with a symbolic link or in the vhost file or Apache setting?
How can this be done?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. I'm posting an example here to help anyone else out.

You need to edit the vhosts file at /etc/httpd/conf/vhosts.conf  and add an Apache Alias directive for that domain.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.245:80>
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@bbgi.com
    DocumentRoot /home/drupal
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com mysite.com
    Alias /iphone/ /home/iphone/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd-www1/www2/be_err_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd-www1/www2/be_log special
    <Directory /home/drupal>
                Options FollowSymLinks +Includes ExecCGI
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The line that I added is:

```
Alias /iphone/ /home/iphone/
```

---

If I wanted an alias for ALL websites on the server when going to http://mysite.com/iphone/  to point to /home/iphone
You need to edit the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file and add this line:

```
AliasMatch ^/iphone/(.*) /home/iphone/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need :

- a symbolic link (with apache option FollowSymLinks)
- or an alias : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Comment: Can you give me an example of what I would write for each option please. Would it be:
    DocumentRoot /home/iphone       
    ServerName mysite.com/iphone

Comment: go to /home/drupal and create a symlink : "ln -s ../iphone iphone"

Comment: That works, but how can I create that for individual sites. That's creating a sym link for all my Drupal sites for /iphone. What if I just need it for mysite.com but not for myothersite.com ?
I have /home/drupal/sites/mysite.com     /home/drupal/sites/myothersite.com, etc...

Comment: Does anyone know how this can be done? I need to be able to set a Drupal website directory to point to another directory on the server.

Comment: You can do this using apache mod_rewrite with a RewriteCond on the domain and a RewriteRule for iphone, take a look at apache doc